# JQuery call to .php file and passing three arguments

Tags: php, jquery

I want to call a .php file and pass three arguments so that the .php files GETS from the query string. I am new to JQuery. Can someone illustrate how to call the .php file using JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get). They provide a few examples that should get you started. The example you're most interested in looks something like this:

```
$.get("myphpfile.php", 
      { param1: "John", param2: "2pm", param3: "Wed" },
      function(data){
           alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
      }
);
```

Comment: The parameters are passed as a JSON object, the data will come back as text by default. jQuery will transform the parameter object to a query string like "myphpfile.php?param1=John&param2=2pm&param3=Wed".